# Unable to import defineEmits interface from another file [Vue3 with script setup + TS]

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, vuejs3

This works good for me:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmits } from 'vue';
import { ProjectInfo } from 'src/ts/types/main';

interface xyzSelectProjectEmits {
    (e: 'projectSelected', selectedProject: ProjectInfo | undefined): void;
}

const emits = defineEmits<xyzSelectProjectEmits>();
```

This, doesn’t:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmits } from 'vue';
import { xyzSelectProjectEmits } from 'some/path'

let x:xyzSelectProjectEmits;
const emits = defineEmits<xyzSelectProjectEmits>();
```

ESLint complains about: “Unsafe assignment of an any value” for `const emits...` but everything goes well with `let x...`

I’m doing something stupid that I’m not seeing right now? Or it’s an ESLint problem?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to currently be a limitation with Vue and typescript. There is an issue open about it on Github https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/4294